# how to find from which application user authenticated in firebase authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am working on this project which has

1. franchise --> website --> jsr_franchise.com
2. customer  --> website --> jsr_customer.com

I am using phone authentication Only.
both use same authentication to login

how do i distinguish wherther user logged in from customer franchise website?
When I use firebase function

```
exports.new_User_Added = functions.auth.user()
    .onCreate(async (user) => {
        database.ref(`/accountCreation/${user.uid}/phoneNumber/`).set(user.phoneNumber)
        database.ref(`/accountCreation/${user.uid}/TIMESTAMP/`).set(admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
        return Promise.resolve()
    })
```

I am able to get phone number and time stamp. But how do I determine? Whether your user used Customer website or franchise website to authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firebase Authentication a user doesn't log in to a specific site, but they log in to the entire Firebase project. No information about what site triggered that log-in is passed to Cloud Functions.

The most common workaround I know of is to pass all the information that is needed to create the user into a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) or [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), [create the account there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), [set a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on their profile with the extra information you want to maintain, and only then sign the user in on the client.